# AJAX don't communicate w/variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, database

Why this not func..if i define #name that string think that #name is null
and no func

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  load();

  function load_data(query) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "searchboss.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        query: query
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
      }
    });
  }

  var search = $("#name").val();

  function load() {
    if (search == '') {
      setInterval(load, 500);
    } else {
      load_data(search);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant markup

Answer (score 0):

Part of this could be moving name lookup into the `load()` function - currently the #name input is pulled on document load, which would be empty.  As user types in information, your search variable isn't updated.  Moving `search` into `load()` would solve that.

```
function load() {
  var search = $("#name").val();

  if (search == '') {
    setInterval(load, 500);
  } else {
    load_data(search);
  }
}
```